# Pointer member is not initialized in copy constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

In my application

```
#include <iostream>

class TestClassA
{

public:
    int* m_ptr;
    TestClassA(int a)
    {
        m_ptr = new int(a);
        std::cout << "Constructor. this: " << this << " m_ptr: " << m_ptr << std::endl;
    }

    TestClassA(const TestClassA& copy)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor. copy: " << &copy << " -> this: " << this << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor. old this->m_ptr: " << m_ptr << std::endl;
        delete m_ptr; // not initialized pointer
        m_ptr = new int;
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor. new this->m_ptr: " << m_ptr << std::endl;
        *m_ptr = *copy.m_ptr;
    }

    // passing by value, thus a copy constructor calls first
    TestClassA& operator=(TestClassA tmp)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy assignment " << this << " <- " << &tmp << std::endl;
        std::swap(m_ptr, tmp.m_ptr);
        return *this;
    }


    ~TestClassA()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor " << this << std::endl;
        delete m_ptr;
        m_ptr = nullptr;
    }
};

void testAssignment()
{
    TestClassA tca1(1);
    std::cout << "tca1.m_ptr: " << tca1.m_ptr << std::endl;

    TestClassA tca2(2);
    std::cout << "tca2.m_ptr: " << tca2.m_ptr << std::endl;
    tca2 = tca1;
}

int main()
{
    testAssignment();
    return 0;
}
```

When I call assignment operator receiving arguments by value, copy constructor calls. I guess it is to create a temporary variable and to copy the state of *tcs1* to it. The issue is that *m_ptr* member of this temporary is not initialized, so I can't delete previous *m_ptr* value to write a new one. What is the proper way of implementing copy constructor in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy constructor is a constructor, not an assignment operator. The diffetence is precisely the absence of preexisting resources to destroy. You don't need to destroy anything, just initialize.

The copy constructor is called because you did not make it accept a const reference:

```
TestClassA& operator=(const TestClassA& tmp)
//                    ^               ^
```

It is the `tmp` parameter that is initialized in the example, not the `this` of the operator.
Of course, you'll need a local variable to get the `swap` trick to work, but at least it will be explicit in your code.

Comment: What if I have pointer to array of 10 int's, but in a copy a pointer to an array of 20 int's comes. First I need to delete my array then allocate more space and then copy all the elements. I cannot just reallocate without deleting the previous data

Comment: @amplifier There is no array to delete for the same reason there isn't one in your `TestClassA(int a)` constructor. You are not trying to delete it there either, do you?

Comment: @NikosC.Yes in my example I don't. But what if I would have such a pointer to array? Wouldn't I need to delete it only in assignment operator, not in copy constructor, right?

Comment: There is not "my" array or "previous m_ptr" in a constructor. Only a yet-to-be-initialized object and fields. The copy constructor is called only because you (erroneously) use a by-value parameter instead of a const reference. It is the parameter that gets initalized using the copy constructor. Not the assigned object.